# "Adding Esperanto circumflexes (supersigno)" option has no effect

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout, special-characters

I'm used to use the keyboard layout option to type the accentuated characters in Esperanto.

This option is in System Settings > Keyboard Layout > Options > Adding Esperanto circumflexes (supersigno) > To the corresponding key in a Qwerty keyboard.

It worked great but since I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04, this option has no effect.

I'm using Ubuntu in French with the keyboard layout French (variant) and Gnome-shell. I tested on another computer with Unity and there is the same issue.

Is it a known issue? I did not find anything about it…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `setxkbmap fr`. It will set your keyboard layout to French and should in your case, have no effect. But for me, it somehow activates my settings in keyboard layout.

If that fixes your problem we're in the same boat with [bug #941718](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/941718).

I have not found a permanent solution yet.

Comment: Indeed, setting another layout as _french_ or _french (variant, latin-9 only)_ activated my layout options. It looks like the _french (variant)_ layout is somehow buggy. Well, looking forward a fix for [bug #941718](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/941718). Thank you!